# What is the difference between 'same', 'typical' and 'similar'?

Tags: meaning, differences, synonyms

What is the difference between *same*, *typical* and *similar*? All of them seem to convey the same meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually they convey different meanings, though similar.

Same: exactly alike, identical: the same dress

Typical:Showing the qualities, traits, or characteristics that identify a group or class:  a typical suburban community.

Similar: alike though not identical: a similar look.

Answer (score 0):

Same: "Justin wore the same shirt that Alice did" implies that Justin wore the exact thing that ALice wore, not just a shirt that looked like the one Alice had worn. 
There is just one shirt under consideration here.

Typical: characteristic (adj.) "Justin wore a shirt that typically Alice wears" implies that Justin wore a shirt that was the kind of shirt that Alice has been observed to wear most of the time.
There are two shirts under consideration here.

Similar: looks/ feels akin (to something). "Justin wore a shirt similar to the one Alice had worn" implies that Justin's shirt looked like Alice's shirt. Note that the shirt could belong to the same company, but the shirt itself isn't the same, as both of them have their own individual shirts (that perhaps look ditto)
There are two shirts underr consideration here.